# Set unicode encoding on all files in folder with c#

Tags: c#, unicode

I have this folder with a bunch of csv files, that I want to import into SQL Server. That works fine with BULK INSERT.

However I have a problem with the encoding, getting weird charters in the db - if I open the csv files in notepad, and save them again as unicode, it works perfect.

Is their a way in C# to programmaticly, convert all files in a folder to unicode?

Thanks

Comment: Or just [set the proper codepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: Its UTF8 - dont think BULK INSERT supports that

Comment: BULK INSERT now supports codepage 65001 (UTF-8) since SqlServer2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all files:

```
        string text = File.ReadAllText("data.txt", Encoding.ASCII);
        File.WriteAllText("data.txt", text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Sandre's answer, you can bulk this operation like this:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"path\to\csvFolder");
var csvFiles = di.EnumerateFiles("*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
var outputFolderDi = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(di.FullName, "outputFolder"));
outputFolderDi.Create();
foreach(var filePath in csvFiles.Select(fi => fi.FullName))
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var newFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolderDi.FullName, fileName);
    File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, text, Encoding.Unicode);
}
```

I make no guarantee that this code is correct. Please check carefully before deploying on your file system!